# virt-install error: Host does not support any virtualization options

Tags: virtualization, centos, xen, damn-small-linux

Completed CentOS 5.4 perfect install from howtoforge.com (ISPConfig 3). I have ISPConfig 3 deployed with a handful of sites. I installed xen:

```
yum install xen kernel-xen
```

I installed the recommended (linuxtopia.org) virtualization packages and started libvirtd

```
yum install virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-python python-virtinst
```

I have damn small linux .iso in /root

```
virt-install --name damnsmall --ram 16 --file=/var/lib/xen/images/damnsmall.img --file-size=1 --vnc --cdrom=/root/current.iso
```

yields the error: ERROR    Host does not support any virtualization options

I have also tried this from GNOME (virt-manager) and I can't even add a connection. I read somewhere I need to reboot with the xen kernel. I dont think I want to do that--though, not really sure why. I need to keep ISPConfig untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udpate: /boot/grub/menu.1st had a new stanza added with the "xen" kernel suffix. Also changed default to 0 in this file.

rebooted and i am at least able to run virt-install.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same problem the other day.  The problem I had was with a BIOS setting.

In my BIOS,  there was an option for "Enable Virtualization", which was disabled by default.  I enabled it, and when I booted up my system, I was able to run `virt-install` with no errors.